# Convert a 3D array (vector) to vtk unstructured mesh

Tags: c++, mesh, vtk

I have a stack of black and white images which I store in my c++ code as a 3D vector containing 0s and 1s. I want to convert this 3D vector into a vtk unstructured mesh with each voxel being an orthogonal element. Is there any library which can do it

Comment: What do you mean by an "orthogonal element"?

Comment: By cubic I mean a hexahedral (HEX_8) type of element. So that during the meshing, each voxel becomes an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create unstructured grids with `vtk` having voxels as elementary cells. Check this [document](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) giving details about the other available cell types. To create such grid, you should parse the content of your vector and create each voxel, then add it to the grid, as done in the following python code (no C++ available to test now but the syntax is easily portable):

```
import vtk

voxelPoints = vtk.vtkPoints()
voxelPoints.SetNumberOfPoints(8)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(0, 0, 0, 0)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(1, 1, 0, 0)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(2, 0, 1, 0)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(3, 1, 1, 0)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(4, 0, 0, 1)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(5, 1, 0, 1)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(6, 0, 1, 1)
voxelPoints.InsertPoint(7, 1, 1, 1)

aVoxel = vtk.vtkVoxel()
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(0, 0)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(1, 1)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(2, 2)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(3, 3)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(4, 4)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(5, 5)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(6, 6)
aVoxel.GetPointIds().SetId(7, 7)

aVoxelGrid = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid()
aVoxelGrid.InsertNextCell(aVoxel.GetCellType(), aVoxel.GetPointIds())
aVoxelGrid.SetPoints(voxelPoints)

aVoxelMapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()
aVoxelMapper.SetInputData(aVoxelGrid)

aVoxelActor = vtk.vtkActor()
aVoxelActor.SetMapper(aVoxelMapper)
aVoxelActor.GetProperty().SetDiffuseColor(1, 0, 0)

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
ren.AddActor(aVoxelActor)

# Render the scene and start interaction.
iren.Initialize()
renWin.Render()
iren.Start()
```